# I need help with a proof: invertibility of $b-\lambda$ in $B$ iff $b-\lambda $ invertible in $A$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital $C^\ast$ algebra and let $B$ be a $\ast$ subalgebra such that $B \oplus \mathbb C = A$ and such that the unit in $B$, $1_B$, is not equal to the unit in $A$. I am trying to show:

If $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ is non-zero then $b-\lambda\cdot 1_B$ is invertible in $B$ if and only if $b-\lambda \cdot 1_A$ is invertible in $A$.

(see Murphy's book at the top of page 45).

I started the proof like this: Let $b-\lambda\cdot 1_B$ be invertible in $B$. Then it is also invertible in $A$. Let $a \in A$ denote its inverse. Then

$$ ba - \lambda 1_B a = 1_A$$

Now the goal is to find $c \in A$ such that $(b -\lambda 1_A)c = 1_A$. Somehow I have to show that $1_B a = 1_A c$ but I can't seem to do it. So this leads nowhere.

Can someone help me prove this please?

Comment: Assuming you mean $b = b 1_B \in B$, then 

\begin{align}
(b-\lambda 1_B)c = 1_B & \Leftrightarrow (c \oplus (- \lambda)^{-1})\cdot (b-\lambda 1_B) \oplus (- \lambda) = 1_A. 
\end{align}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $(b-\lambda 1_B)c=1_B$.

When we use $1_A=(0,1)$,
$$
[(b, 0) - \lambda (0,1)](x,t)=(b,-\lambda)(x,t)=\left(bx-\lambda x+tb, -\lambda t\right).
$$
Looking at the second coordinate, $t=-1/\lambda$. Then the equality in the first coordinate becomes 
$$
0=bx-\lambda x -\frac1\lambda b=(b-\lambda 1_B)x-\frac1\lambda b,
$$
So $x=\frac1\lambda cb=\frac1\lambda 1_B+c $. That is, in $A$ we have $(b-\lambda 1_A)^{-1}=\frac1\lambda cb=\frac1\lambda 1_B+c-\frac1\lambda  1_A$.

The computations above also allow us to do the converse: if $b-\lambda 1_A$ is invertible in $A$, then $x$ above exists. Now take $c=x-\frac1\lambda 1_B$, and a straightforward calculation shows that $(b-\lambda 1_B)c=1_B$.

Comment: Why can you use $(0,1) = 1_A$? Is the argument that every unital $C^\ast$-algebra is isomorphic to its unitisation?

Comment: It's not about the unitization.  In a unital C$^*$-algebra, the unit is identified with the complex number $1$. So if $A=B+\mathbb C$ with $B$ non-unital, $1_A$ is necessarily $0+1$.

Comment: How do I see this? Is it because a unital $C^\ast$-algebra contains $\mathbb C$ as a subalgebra? (but wouldn't then the unit in any commutative unital Banach algebra be identified with $1 \in \mathbb C$?)

Comment: In this case, $B$ is not unital (in $A$), so $B\cap \mathbb C=\{0\}$, i.e. it's a direct sum. But it is even simpler than that. When you consider $\mathbb C\subset A$, you actually mean $\mathbb C\,1_A$.

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb C 1_A$ is what I meant but if this is the identification wouldn't it mean that every commutative unital Banach algebra contains $\mathbb C$ as a subalgebra?

Comment: Of course. And you don't need commutative.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this part in the book and I just asked another related question. I will accept your answer shortly, please do not worry.

Comment: Don't worry, I don't worry ;)

Comment: Regarding your first comment above: but $B$ in this case is unital. Can you still identify $1_A$ with $(0,1)$? Shouldn't the unit in $A$ be instead $(1_B, 1_A)$?

Comment: If $B$ is unital with the same unit as $A$, then $B+\mathbb C$ is not a direct sum, and basically nothing said above applies.

Comment: No, I meant that in the question $B$ is unital with $1_B\neq 1_A$. But in your comment you use that $B$ is non-unital. So my question is: is your first comment above still applicable?

Comment: When I said "non-unital" I meant "without the unit of $A$"

Comment: But if you identify $B$ with $B\times \{0\}$ then $1_B = (1_B,0)$. To get $t=-1/\lambda$ in your answer you have identified $1_B$ with $1_A = (0,1)$. ($b-\lambda 1_B \in \operatorname{Inv}{(B)}$ means there is $(x,t)\in B$ such that $(b-\lambda 1_B)(x,t) = 1_B$. Also, if $(x,t)\in B$ then $t=0$. No?

Comment: No, what I wrote in my answer (as required by the question) is $b-\lambda\,1_A$.

Comment: if $b-\lambda1_A$ is invertible with inverse $c$ in $A$ . then what is inverse of $b-\lambda1_B$ in $B$ ??

Comment: is it $c- \frac{1_A}{\lambda}-\frac{1_B}{\lambda}$

Comment: I think it's $c+\frac1\lambda\,1_A-\frac1\lambda\,1_B$.